# There is an error in alignment

Tags: c

When I get 'N real data, calculate the average of the remaining data except the largest data and the smallest data.' I wrote the following code. I created it using Quick Alignment, but it is not aligned properly, resulting in errors. Where is the problem? (In the code, N was written in m and this is the code to check if the alignment is good:

`[for (i = 0; i < m; i++) { printf("%lf ", arr[i]); }]`

This is my complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bans(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(double *)a - *(double *)b);
}

int main() 
{ 
    int m, i;
    double a = 0;
    double* arr;
    scanf("%d", &m);
    arr = (double*) malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &arr[i]);
    }
    qsort(arr, m, sizeof(arr[0]), bans);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      printf("%lf ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n"); 
    for (i = 1; i < m - 1; i++) {
      a += arr[i];
    } 
    printf("%.4lf", a / (m - 2));
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(int) * m);` ==> `malloc(sizeof(double) * m);`, or better, `malloc(sizeof *arr * m);`

Comment: The return value from `bans` is also incorrect. You have perhaps been looking at an example which sorts `int` values. You must explicitly do `if(*(double *)a > *(double *)b) return 1;` etc. In any case, even for `int` values the subtraction method is a bad idea, since the calculation can overflow.

Comment: This code is a perfect example of why casting is almost always a bad idea.  Never cast the return of malloc().  Never malloc() based on sizeof(int), your malloc ought to be `arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * m)` which will always be correct, even if you change the type of arr, or change to a machine where ints/floats/doubles are different relative sizes than on the machine you developed on.

Answer (score 0):

OP is not allocating the proper sized memory  with `sizeof(int)` for `double* arr;`. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505475/there-is-an-error-in-alignment/46506349#comment79965256_46505475).

Best to determine the size based of the size of of the de-referenced valuable than the type. [@Jabberwock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505475/there-is-an-error-in-alignment/46506349#comment79967171_46505475).  It is easier to code, review and maintain.

```
double* arr;
...
// arr = (double*) malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * m);
```

Also, no need to cast the return value.

---

The compare function may overflow too.  To avoid that:

```
int bans(const void *a, const void *b) {
  // return (*(double *)a - *(double *)b);
  return (*(double *)a > *(double *)b) - (*(double *)a < *(double *)b);
}
```

On a pedantic note, FP values may include [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).  When sorting such, recommend to always put NaN at the end of the sorted list.  Later processing could then easily shorten the list as often when `NaN` are present is a list, they are meant to be discarded.  Code as needed for that select case.

```
int bans(const void *a, const void *b) {
  double *ad = *((const double *)a);
  double *bd = *((const double *)a);
  if (ad > bd) return 1;
  if (ad < bd) return -1;
  if (ad == bd) return 0;

  at least 1 of ad,ab is a NaN
  return 1; // adjust per coding goals
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bans(const void *a, const void *b)
  {
  return(*(double *)a - *(double *)b);
  }

int main()
  {
  int m, i;
  double a = 0;
  double *arr;

  printf("Number of elements: ");
  scanf("%d", &m);
  /* Casting the "void *" returned from malloc() is not needed. */
  /* Changed sizeof(int) to sizeof(double) */
  arr = malloc(sizeof(double) * m);
  for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
     {
     printf("Enter element %d of %d: ", i+1, m);   
     scanf("%lf", &arr[i]);
     }

  /* Sort the entries from highest to lowest */
  qsort(arr, m, sizeof(arr[0]), bans);

  for(i = 1; i < (m-1); i++)
     {
     a += arr[i];
     }

  printf("Average, minus largest and smallest: %.4lf\n", a / (m - 2));

  free(arr);
  return 0;
  }
```

Example execution:

```
Number of elements: 5
Enter element 1 of 5: 4.2
Enter element 2 of 5: 9.1
Enter element 3 of 5: 2.3
Enter element 4 of 5: 9.9
Enter element 5 of 5: 0.2
Average, minus largest and smallest: 5.2000
```

Comment: @chux, oops... my bad.  Thanks.  (fixed)